# List item numbers incorrectly display AFTER floated content

Tags: css, list, css-float

I have a list where the numbering is positioned inside each list item.  Each list item contains floated content, either floated left or right.  The problem is that the list numbering is being rendered to the RIGHT of the first left-floated element, when the numbering is intended to be the first thing on each line.

Here is a [working example of the issue](http://jsbin.com/ulebus/6/edit).  I found the issue to be happening in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9 (haven't tested other browsers).  I've also included the relevant code below.

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <div class="name">Fingers</div>
        <div class="count">10</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="name">Arms</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="name">Heads</div>
        <div class="count">1</div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
ol {
    list-style: decimal inside none;
}

ol li .name {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ol li .count {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Edit:** Per my comment below, it is important that the numbering remain INSIDE the list item.  The reason is that I want borders between each list item, and I want the numbering to be within the frame of the border, not outside of it.

Comment: Any compelling reason you can't keep the list number outside?

Comment: @DiMono - I've updated the linked example to take you to http://jsbin.com/ulebus/6/edit.  You'll see I have a `border-bottom` on the `li` elements.  I'd like the border to span the entire `li`, including the numbering.  If I leave the numbering outside, it isn't taken into account when using a border.

Comment: @smclark89 - I want the count on the right and the name on the left, though.  Note that "count" and "numbering" are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED:

```
ol li {
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

}

ol {
    list-style: decimal inside;
}

ol li .name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ol li .count {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, interesting.  So you essentially solved it by removing the `float:left` from the first element in each list item, and instead using `display:inline-block`.  I'll give that a shot, though I still don't understand why it rendered the way it did in the first place. :)

Comment: Works for me. Nicely done. Note that leaving .count as float: right also works.

Comment: also you can add `ol {width: 165px}` to limit width of rows.

Comment: @MattHuggins When you display the number inside, it gets treated as regular content. When you float an html element, it moves to the left of regular content, even if that content appears ahead of it in the html.

Comment: @DiMono - that part I understand.  But CSS does not seem to supply a way to then float that number to the left, which seems like a bug or missed feature.

Comment: It's not CSS issue, it's rather browsers behavior. I think that number is rendered as inline element.

Comment: Well, it's not really an element you can get a handle on; if anyone knows how to get a handle on the list identifier, I'd honestly love to see it.